# Issue with CSS3 transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the reference from this [Rotate image with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396614/rotate-image-with-onclick) , I am trying to apply a css3 transition to a div, when the div element is clicked. The demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2BWm8/54/) Everything is working perfect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="testRotate">Test rotate</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.testRotate{
 width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.testRotate.rotate{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click( function(){
        $(this).addClass("rotate");
        setTimeout(function(){$("div").removeClass("rotate");}, 1500);
    });
});
```

In this example, when onclicking the div, **rotate** class will be applied to it, so it will rotate for 360 degree, as defined in css. After sometimes we are removing the **rotate** class, so again the div is rotating back to its original position.

Now what i need is, when it clicked the element is has to rotate for 360 degree, but it should not suppose to rotate back once the **rotate** class got removed from it.

Comment: You cant do that. You;d need to look into potentially using `animation` instead of `transition` and combining it with `animation-fill-mode` to let it apply the previous effect when it ends. (Animation fill mode to the rescue! Heres a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new class for transition and remove rotate as well as the class for transition.

```js
 $(function(){
        $("div").click( function(){
            $(this).addClass("testRotate rotate");
            setTimeout(function(){$("div").removeClass("testRotate rotate");}, 1500);
        });
    });
```

```css
    .test {
       width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      margin-top: 50px;  
    }
    .testRotate{
      -moz-transition: transform 1s;
      -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    
    .testRotate.rotate{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="test testRotate">Test rotate</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2BWm8/60/)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BWm8/55/)

```
$("div").click(function() {
    if (  $(this).css( "transform" ) == 'none' ){
        $(this).css("transform","rotate(360deg)");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform","");
    }
});
```