# Rotate image every time on click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate an image every time I click on it.. I've created a function to do this but the image only rotate the first time I click on it... Moreover, once the image rotate it change automatically the width and height.. How can I keep the same width and height every time??

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
      $(this).rotate(45)       
    })
})
```

Comment: Where does `.rotate()` come from? It is not part of the standard jQuery library

Comment: I've used this library: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-rotate/downloads

Comment: why plugin when you can do it with `css` properties in `jquery`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I think I'll try to do it using css properties in JQuery then  :)

Comment: Cool. try it and let us know if you face any problems.. :)

Comment: Also the image's width/height does not change, the bounding box's width/height changes. To keep the bounding box's dimensions the same you would either have to crop the rotated image or scale the image.

Comment: here's [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17348698/3591300) to your question.

Comment: The plugin converts the `img` into a `canvas`, that's the reason the click not working for second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done by using just javascript, working example would be like this

```
<div id="imgWrapper">
    <img src="Desert.jpg" id="image" onclick="rotateBy10Deg(this)">  
</div>

<script>
    var delta =0;
    function rotateBy10Deg(ele){
        ele.style.webkitTransform="rotate("+delta+"deg)";
        delta+=10;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin converts the `img` into a `canvas`, that's the reason the click not working for second time. Change your jQuery or refer this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/nmvtaLvs/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this).rotate(45);
  });
  $('body').on('click', 'canvas', function() {
    $(this).rotate(45);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting `max-height` and `max-width` in your CSS file.  This will ensure the image doesn't exceed a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you out:

[Rotate image with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396614/rotate-image-with-onclick)

Taken straight from that link in case you don't want to click:

Javascipt

```
var rotate_factor = 0;

function rotateMe(e) {
    rotate_factor += 1;
    var rotate_angle = (180 * rotate_factor) % 360;
    $(e).rotate({angle:rotate_angle});
}
```

HTML

```
<img src='blue_down_arrow.png' onclick='rotateMe(this);' /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the angle (45 degree) is calculated in reference to its initial angle that is 0. Once the image is in 45 degree it will only have to rotate if the angle changes (eg 90). So the below code may work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var angle = 0;
$("img").click(function () {
      angle = angle+45;
  $(this).rotate(angle); 
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as you suggested, I used css in JQuery:

css:

```
.rotate:active {
transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").click(function () {
//forcing img to rotate every time on click()
            if ($(this).css("transform")=='none') {
                $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
            }
            else {
                $(this).css("transform","")
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I changed the degrees to 180 instead of 45 because I realized it's better for what I want to do...