# How to rotate an image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and each time I click on it I want to make it rotate 180 degrees. This is the code I tried:

```
<img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant" src="../stdicons/GeomindIcons/slide.png"/>
```

```js
$('#showLayers').click( function() { 
    $('#showLayers img').animate({ rotate: 180 });
});
```

This code does not work for some reason. Any ideas why the above code does not work?

Comment: Go through this stack overflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396614/rotate-image-with-onclick) may be it can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS rotation cross browser with jquery.animate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191058/css-rotation-cross-browser-with-jquery-animate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that your issue is because the selector is incorrect. It should be `$('#showLayers')` not `$('#showLayers img')` - or even just `$(this)` as you're in the scope of the click handler.

Secondly, note that you can improve the logic by using CSS for the animation and simply toggling the class in JS as needed:

```js
$('#showLayers').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
#showLayers {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant" src="https://i.imgur.com/J5YLlJvl.png" width="250" />
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.animate()` method in jQuery accepts only integers as a value to a property so "180deg" is invalid instead create a class and toggle it

```js
$(document).on('click', ".a", function() {
  $(".a").toggleClass('a_rotated');
})
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.a_rotated {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var rot =180;
    function rotateImage(test){
        test.style.webkitTransform="rotate("+rot+"deg)";

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="imgWrapper">
    <img src="test.png" id="image" onclick="rotateImage(this)">  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can use the `jquery` `css` methods with `rotate`. With a variable you increm, your pictures rotate at 360 deg (180 by 180).

Please try:

```js
var angle = 0;
$('#showLayers').click(function() {
  angle += 180
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle+'deg)'); 
});
```

```css
#showLayers {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant" src="https://i.imgur.com/J5YLlJvl.png" width="250" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('#showLayers').click( function() {

    $('#showLayers img').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Below is one of the way:

```
var inti = 180;

$('img').click(function(){     
     var rotate = "rotate(" + inti + "deg)";
            var trans = "all 0.3s ease-out";
    $(this).css({
         "-webkit-transform": rotate,
                "-moz-transform": rotate,
                "-o-transform": rotate,
                "msTransform": rotate,
                "transform": rotate,
                "-webkit-transition": trans,
                "-moz-transition": trans,
                "-o-transition": trans,
                "transition": trans
    });
    inti += 180;
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/1464bgn2/

Answer (score -1):

Change `showLayers img` to `#showLayers`.

Also `rotate: 180` isn't valid styling. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191130/828709) for how to rotate a div.